# Modifying a record before saving in database using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

As usual here is the code in my save button:

```
Private Sub Tbl_Student_InformationBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click ...
        Me.Validate()
        Me.Tbl_Student_InformationBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.EnrollmentDataSet)
End Sub
```

Before saving, I need to modify one of the columns in the record to be saved. But how can I access it?

I tried to modify the field of the column named "Status" into "Active". Here is the code I decided to append just before `Me.Validate()`.

```
Me.Tbl_Student_InformationBindingSource.Item("Status") = "Active"
```

This is wrong but it must be look like this, I think.

Comment: What is the data type of column Status ? If it is an enum or foreign key ID you probably need to set it to the equivalent integer/enum value instead of a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after two months(I stopped using VB.net previously) I end up doing this:

```
Me.EnrollmentDataSet.Tables("tbl_Student_Information").Rows(Tbl_Student_InformationBindingSource.Position).Item("Status") = "Active"
```

I placed that code snippet just after the UpdateAll method, then after this(the code above), I called another UpdateAll.

This is one way to solve my problem, but I think there must be a better one.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Tbl_Student_InformationBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click ...
    Me.Validate()
    Me.EnrollmentDataSet.Status="Active"
    Me.Tbl_Student_InformationBindingSource.EndEdit()        
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.EnrollmentDataSet)
End Sub
```